# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableInputFormat

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, hbase

I am using sparklauncher to start a spark application. In spark application I am inserting data into hive table and using some hbase-hive linked table in join query. I have added hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0-cdh5.13.0.jar in the spark launcher, still I ma getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableInputFormat i have added jar in sparklauncher error:

```
def launch(hdfsFilePath:String):Unit={
    println("Inside ApplicationLauncher")
    val command = new SparkLauncher()
      .setAppResource("/home/cloudera/Desktop/Avi/LiveProjects/MusicDataAnalysis/target/scala-2.11/musicdataanalysis_2.11-0.1.jar")
      .setMainClass("ParseInputFile")
      .setVerbose(false)
      .addAppArgs(hdfsFilePath)
      .setMaster("local")
      .addJar("/home/cloudera/Desktop/Avi/jars/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0-cdh5.13.0.jar")
      .addJar("/home/cloudera/Desktop/Avi/jars/spark-xml_2.11-0.5.0.jar")

    println("Done with Spark Launcher")
    val appHandle = command.startApplication()
    appHandle.addListener(new SparkAppHandle.Listener{
      def infoChanged(sparkAppHandle : SparkAppHandle) : Unit = {
      //  println(sparkAppHandle.getState + "  Custom Print")
      }

      def stateChanged(sparkAppHandle : SparkAppHandle) : Unit = {
        println(sparkAppHandle.getState)
        if ("FINISHED".equals(sparkAppHandle.getState.toString)){
          sparkAppHandle.stop
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem got solved when I have added hbase-0.92.1.jar along with hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0-cdh5.13.0.jar. Please find the below working code:

```
def launch(hdfsFilePath:String):Unit={
println("Inside ApplicationLauncher")
val command = new SparkLauncher()
  .setAppResource("/home/cloudera/Desktop/Avi/LiveProjects/MusicDataAnalysis/target/scala-2.11/musicdataanalysis_2.11-0.1.jar")
  .setMainClass("ParseInputFile")
  .setVerbose(false)
  .addAppArgs(hdfsFilePath)
  .setMaster("local")
  .addJar("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Avi/jars/hbase-0.92.1.jar")
  .addJar("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Avi/jars/hive-hbase-handler-3.1.1.jar")
  .addJar("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Avi/jars/spark-xml_2.11-0.5.0.jar")
println("Done with Spark Launcher")
val appHandle = command.startApplication()
appHandle.addListener(new SparkAppHandle.Listener{
  def infoChanged(sparkAppHandle : SparkAppHandle) : Unit = {
  //  println(sparkAppHandle.getState + "  Custom Print")
  }

  def stateChanged(sparkAppHandle : SparkAppHandle) : Unit = {
    println(sparkAppHandle.getState)
    if ("FINISHED".equals(sparkAppHandle.getState.toString)){
      sparkAppHandle.stop
    }
  }
})
```

}